# .NET: Import Excel files, which are a embedded in a resource file, into a dataset

Tags: c#, .net, excel, dataset

I have a **resource** file with some **embedded Excel files**. How can I **import** these files into **datasets**? I found several **libraries** / **code snippets** which works for files, which are on the harddisk, but nothing if the files are part of a resource file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the file as a stream with **[ResourceManager.GetStream()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxee5096%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)** and pass it to the "open" function in your favorite library to process Excel files. They usually support open(Stream) methods, if not, you should write the stream in a **temporary file**...

To dump the excel lines as records in a dataset: loop into the excel rows and insert a new record by line with the desired **correspondency between excel columns and datatable columns**.